# what kind of E this is?

Tags: probability-theory

[image]

I could not figure out what kind of expectation is C because clearly it is not for a binomial distribution.
Any help would be appreciated a lot!

Thanks,

Comment: it's Bernoulli: and it's E[x] = p

Comment: @user29418 it’s actually Binomial and $\mathbb{E}(X)=np$ with $n=100$ and $p=1/2$

Comment: @NapD.Lover Actually it's neither. The binomial distribution with $n=100$ and $p=1/2$ would have $P(X=k) =\binom{100}{k} (1/2)^k(1/2)^{100-k}=\binom{100}{k}(1/2)^{100}$.

Comment: oh you're right I messed that up, sorry!

Comment: @kccu good catch.

Comment: $\sum_{k=0}^{100} {100 \choose k} (1/2)^k \approx 4.065 \cdot 10^{17} \neq 1$ so it is not even a valid PMF, anyway. The problem might have a typo in it.

Comment: Note that you *could* interpret this as $E\left[ X \cdot \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{100-X}\right]$ where $X$ has the distribution $\text{Binomial}(n=100,p=1/2)$, but the only way I could think to actually compute this expectation is to compute the sum as saulspatz did in their answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By the binomial theorem, $$
\left(1+{x\over2}\right)^{100}=\sum_{k=0}^{100}{100\choose k}{x^k\over2^k}$$
Differentiate both sides:$$
50\left(1+{x\over2}\right)^{99}=\sum_{k=1}^{100}k{100\choose k}{x^{k-1}\over2^k}$$
Set $x=1$:
$$50\cdot\left(\frac32\right)^{99}=\sum_{k=1}^{100}k{100\choose k}\left(\frac12\right)^k$$